# Prove that the trigonometric series of functions converges uniformly and absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

Prove that this particular series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^2(cos(nx^2))}{e^n(x^2+1)}$ converges uniformly and absolutely in $\mathbf{R}$.

I can think of how to construct other series that are larger than this series and yet convergent, which would prove convergence by comparison. But I do not know a rigorous proof for uniform and absolute convergence. If someone could provide a thorough proof for both, that would be very helpful for my understanding.

Comment: Follows directly from Weierstrass M-test...

Comment: How so? It would really help if you could explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$\left|\frac{nx^2(\cos(nx^2))}{e^n(x^2+1)}\right|\leq \frac{n}{e^n}<\frac{6}{n^2}$$ the claim follows from Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: How did you go from $\frac{n}{e^n}$ to $\frac{6}{n^2}$?

Comment: $e^n=1+n+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n^3}{6}+....> \frac{n^3}{6} $

Comment: Also, one other question I have is this. The Weistrass M-test allows us to say that this converges uniformly. How do we conclusively say it converges absolutely?

Comment: It says it converges uniformly and absolutely both.

Comment: For the above case, instead of saying $\frac{6}{n^2}$, we could have alternatively said that the term is less than or equal to $\frac{2}{n}$, by using the same logic, no?

Comment: yes, but then $\sum \frac{2}{n}$ is not convergent.